# Problem in converting the varchar value '1.33' to data type int

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 5 case statements (just showing 2 case statements only).

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       CASE [GRADE1]
         when 1 then 1
         when 2 then 3
         when 3 then 5
         when 4 then 7
         when 5 then 9
       End as Q1,
       CASE [GRADE2]
         when 1 then 1
         when 2.3 then 3
         when 3.33 then 5
         when 4.67 then 7
         when 1 then 9
       End as Q2
  FROM abcd
```

---

Here I am trying to put the values in temp  table which I need to map in later select syntax

```
SELECT a,b     
  INTO #Temp_Q
  FROM xyz 
 WHERE [ds]= 'Data'

   select distinct t.[b] as [Q]
     from abcd s
left join #Temp_Q t on s.[GRADE1]  = t.[a]
                       s.[GRADE2]  = T.[a]
```

Instead of hardcoding all these values  i am asked to write code.

Now i am getting error.. And don't know how to convert. [GRADE2] (FLOAT,NULL) is the datatype assinged in the column.

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.33' to data type int.

Comment: What are the data types of table xyz and table abcd? You need to convert all the datatypes to decimal, either in the orginal tables or the query.  BTW do not ever use float for things that you intend to do calulcations on, it creates rounding errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.33 isn't an integer**, it's a `DECIMAL`.  There is a decimal and numbers after the decimal, so it can't be represented as an integer i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4.  You need to use either `CAST` or `CONVERT` before processing that field.

Answer (score 0):

Try a SELECT CAST(a AS INT) or SELECT CONVERT(INT, a) and let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

@JNK is correct. However, I'd change the data type in the temp table to decimal. The rule of thumb is to keep the data type consistent throughout all stages of processing. Since "1.01" is decimal, keep it decimal in storage too.